# What is the "correct" way to import same similar data from different folders?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a structure like this:

```
/src
  /folder1
    index.ts
    /PreHooks
      hook1.ts
      hook2.ts
    /PostHooks
      hook1.ts
      hook2.ts
  /folder2
    index.ts
    /PreHooks
      hook1.ts
      hook2.ts
  /folder3
    index.ts
    /PostHooks
      hook1.ts
      hook2.ts
main.ts
```

Rough example of what I have

hook*.ts

```
export default (agrs) => something
```

index.ts

```
import prehook1 from './PreHooks/prehook1'
import posthook1 from "./PostHooks/posthook1";
import prehook2 from './PreHooks/prehook2'
import posthook2 from "./PostHooks/posthook2";

export const prehooks = [
   prehook1,
   prehook2,
]

export const posthooks = [
    posthook1,
    posthook2,
]
```

main.ts

```
import { folder1PreHooks } from "./src/folder1";
import { folder1PostHooks } from "./src/folder1";
import { folder2PreHooks } from "./src/folder1";
...


module.exports.preHooks = [
    ...folder1PreHooks,
    ...folder2PreHooks,
]

module.exports.postHooks = [
    ...folder1PostHooks,
    ...folder3PostHooks
]
```

I don't have much experience with JS, but I feel like I'm approaching the import/export structure completely wrong. Can you give some suggestions on how to do it properly? There will be a lot of such folders, so, ideally, I would like to have some kind of "plug-in" logic, i.e. you can add a new folder with some exported hooks and it will be loaded automatically, but I could not find any information on how to do this or if it's possible at all

Comment: There are build scripts that can automatically generate such *index.js* files, and you could manually load all files from the folders dynamically, but in general no JS will not automatically load modules just because they exist.